# Returns only the first item in string array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to get a list of string values from a Web API, into an application.

This is the array of values in my Web Api that I want to get:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "Item1", "Item2s", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5" };
}
```

The following code is used to get the data from the Web Api

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:1234/api/items");

var items = new List<Items>();

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    // Parse 1 Product from the content
    var ItemsSet= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);


    var ItemData = new Items
    (
    (string)ItemsSet[0], 
                (string)ItemsSet[1],
                (string)ItemsSet[2],
                (string)ItemsSet[3],
                (string)ItemsSet[4]
    );

    Items.Add(ItemData);
}
```

But this returns only the first value in the string[], ie, "Item1".

How do I fix this to get all the values in the array?

Comment: What is only returning one item? Is the the `ItemsSet`? or is it `Items`?

Comment: `Items` only returns one.

Answer (score 0):

I think..
Take itemset as an array.how have taken it as a variable.`var[] itemset`